# How can i implement Editor like Wiki provides using JSP, html, java script

Tags: jsp, editor

I Have application is implemented in JSP, HTML, JS, CSS and now i want provide a interface to enter news information, where title and textarea where news can be entered, for text area i want provide features like Bold, font, formation, could you pleas help me to find a way for it. I wan to use only open source and this tool should be able to run in any browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use any Wysiwyg editors. Example TinyMCE, CKEditor etcc.

Comment: Yes you can, In case of tinyMCE just add a javascript to your page. then it identifies the textarea's and calls the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: @Maruthi., Thanks for your response, finally i have used JQuery plugin.